# Difference of hypercyclic operator and identity

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory

Let $B$ be a separable Banach space, $L:B \to B$ be a hypercyclic operator, $k>0$, $I_B$ the identity on $B$, and define $L_k: =k (I_B -  L)$.  When is $L_k$ hypercyclic on $B$?  Can anything else be said about $L_k$?

Comment: Do you mean $L_k:=k(I_B-L)$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if anything can be said in general. If $k>0$ is small enough, then the norm of $L_k$ will be less than $1$ and hence $L_k$ cannot be hypercyclic. For other values of $k$, the spectrum of $L_K$ will be
$$
k(1-\sigma(L))
$$
and thus it may not be true that every component of $\sigma(L_k)$  intersects the unit circle (and hence it will not be hypercyclic). My feeling (but I don't know for sure) that except for very special cases, $L_k$ will not be hypercyclic (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Thanks Ruben,  I had a similar intuition.